# Insert Results of UserName API Into File Path

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, filenames, ole

I have a problem that has stumped me for the last day.

I have a GetUserName Api which extracts the name of the current user, it works perfectly.

I also have an unbound OLE Object that is being controlled on form load by this.

```
With Me.OLE1  
.Class = "Excel.Sheet"    
.OLETypeAllowed = acOLELinked    
.SourceDoc = "C:\Users\" & GetUserName & "\Desktop\Database\Excel Files\Bulk Updating.xlsm"    
.SourceItem = "R1C1:R5C5"    
.Action = acOLECreateLink    
.SizeMode = acOLESizeClip    
End With
```

When I run the code I get Runtime Error 2101 on Line 4.

When I set Line 4 to Jblogs instead of my get user function it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the result of `GetUserName` to a string variable first, as in

```
Dim strUser As String
strUser = GetUserName
```

and then try using that variable in your string concatenation. If necessary check `Len(strUser)` to see if it has any "funny" trailing characters like blanks, nulls, or similar.